# Continuously watching for file change in PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

I have a log file which is building while a certain code is running. There exists a time step in this file that is changing and is important for my data analysis, since in each time step another file is overwritten. What I need is to have a python code which generate a few random integer for time steps let say 5 integer. I want to write a code to continuously monitor the log file and for the mentioned time step copy the overwritten file to certain directory.

Let me summarize it:

the log file contains some lines as the following
1 blablabla
2 blablabla
3 blablabla
.
.
.
1000 blablabla

there is a file which will be overwritten in each step and I need to keep a few of them randomly. I want to save the corresponding created file of the random number in a directory while the main code is running and the log file is changing.

This is what I tried so far

```
def read_file():
    with open("log file", "r") as f:
        SMRF1 = f.readlines()
    return SMRF1

import os                                    #import library
import shutil                                #import library
import sys                                   #import library
import numpy as np

lower_limit = 500
upper_limit = 1000
size = 5
X1 = np.random.randint(lower_limit, upper_limit, size=(5,))
#print(type(X1))
selected_steps = np.sort(X1)
print(selected_steps)

os.mkdir("mkdir")  #make a directory 

with open('log file') as f:
    if 'random_time_step' in f.read():
        shutil.copy2("f1", "mkdir") #f1 is the file which will be overwritten in each step
```

but it is not monitoring the log file during the execution time. How to force it to watch for changes in log file?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: if you just want to know *if* something was changed (and not *what*), take a look at `os.path.getmtime()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use generator to monitor changes in file. checkout this example.

```
import time
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2) # Go to the end of the file
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1) # Sleep briefly
            continue
        yield line
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to modify the code with including the generator. But now it becomes an infinite loop. Could you please kindly comment on the code.